# Inheriting Generic Types

Tags: .net, generics, inheritance, .net-4.6.1

### Assumptions

1. I already know the framework does not allow the pattern to be discussed, in the example
2. I have a need that would benefit from a more simple application of the Generic pattern.

### Context

I am reviewing code for a client and identified a handful of Static/Instance methods that are reliably implemented across several Classes/Structs.

I am looking for an approach, similar to the Example, that will allow for the design described to be performed.

### Example

```
public class StaticObject<T>: T where T: class, new(){
    public void Method1(){}
    public int Method2(){}
}

public class Object : StaticObject<KeyedCollection<string, object>>{

}
```

## Question

***What alternative means could i leverage to obtain the ability to have a class inherit from the Generic `T` and have exposed the two Static methods?***

[image]

Comment: Ah I overlooked the problem, you want that the generic class inherits from its own generic parameter....so I still don't get my head around what this would mean and be used for in real life. Can you give a real life example what that should do? Maybe it's an xy-problem and there are different approaches to what you _actually_ try to achieve.

Comment: I guess I could have a dummy Interface and apply Extensions against that Interface

Comment: @GoldBishop - I'm struggling to understand the application of this too. If I had a `StaticObject<string>` then the two methods would have to use reflection to see that `T` was in fact `string`. It seems to negate the value of inheritance in the first place. What real-world example does this approach apply to?

Comment: `StaticObject<string>`, `StaticObject<KeyedCollection<string, object>>`, `StaticObject<CustomClass>`....it would allow me to define a common set of methods and each inheriting class would have access and expose them accordingly; while inheriting from the Generic `T` for purpose

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, your code compiles with some minor corrections https://dotnetfiddle.net/G0s77E

Comment: No it does not....`StaticObject<T>: T where T: class, new()` the 4.6.1 compiler screems on the Generic `T` inheritance on my system.

Comment: @Jodrell your design was not equivalent to my question...here is the correct equivalent to my question: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zDt9kx

Comment: Ah, I see, you want to multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Jodrell more like a wrapper pass through inheritance....the `StaticObject` class would inherit from the Generic with added members

Comment: @Jodrell hence the reason I was asking for alternative approach to obtaining the desired approach...everyone is missing the `alternative approach` part of the question...think outside of the box

Comment: Indeed, there is no support for either generic inheritance or multiple inheritance in C#. You want something like what is achieved in various mocking frameworks

Comment: Do `Method1` and `Method2` have any relationship to `T` or an instance of `T`?

Comment: @Jodrell no....those are the standard methods to be available to multiple objects....It becomes a scenario where the Generic `T` is not relevant to those methods, as they leverage methods off of `Object` to perform tasks.  I am looking for an alternative that could perform the task, since the Generic framework is limited (by design).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe you want something like this.

```
using System;

public interface INeededForMethod1
{
    ...
}

public interface INeededForMethod2
{
    ...
}

public class GenericExtender<T>
{
    public T @Object { get; }
    private Func<T, INeededForMethod1> Method1Helper { get; }
    private Func<T, INeededForMethod2> Method2Helper { get; }

    public GenericExtender(
            Func<T> constructor,
            Func<T, INeededForMethod1> method1Helper,
            Func<T, INeededForMethod2> method2Helper)
   {
       this.Object = constructor();
       this.Method1Helper = method1Helper;
       this.Method2Helper = method2Helper;
   }

   public void Method1()
   {
       var method1Stuff = this.Method1Helper(this.@Object);
       ...
   }

   public void Method2()
   {
       var method2Stuff = this.Method2Helper(this.@Object);
       ...
   }        
}
```

The details are flexible, If you could require an interface from `T` you could compose that in to the implementation of `GenericExtender<T>`.